# what exactly is the phytree object in matlab?

Tags: matlab

This question has bothered me for a while, so I post it here just in case someone else has the similar issue. After debugging the code to ask it print out the variables, I understand that the phytree object is a struct array with three fields, i.e., tree, dist and names. Here, tree is a matrix with the size the number of branches times 2. But because the data is large, I cannot quite figure out what exactly is the matrix tree. Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use the seqneighjoin function to generate the phytree.

Comment: My guess after reading http://cda.psych.uiuc.edu/matlab_pdf/bioinfo_ug.pdf is that it is the tree description in the Newick tree format

Comment: n.p. can't really help much since idk this toolbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `seqneighjoin` is not a struct array with the fields `tree` `dist` and `names`, it's a `phytree` object that has some internal properties called `tree`, `dist` and `names`. Since you're already taking a look at the code with the debugger, take a look at the line right at the end of `phytree.m` - you'll see that it specifies that the output `tr` is an object of class `phytree`, not a struct.

I'm not sure if you have much background using object-oriented programming in MATLAB, but it's a bigger topic than I can discuss here - I'll just say that an "object" is something that has *properties* that store information in the same way that a struct has fields that store information; but an object also has *methods* that are functions stored as part of the object and that act on it. For the `phytree` object, these methods are functions such as `prune` for removing branches, `getnewickstr` for getting a Newick-formatted string, and so on.

You can find out more about MATLAB OO programming in the documentation. Unfortunately, there's a bit of an issue with that - in R2008a, MATLAB introduced a new form of OO, and all the current documentation is based on that style of OO. `phytree` is implemented using the old style of OO, so you may need to look at the doc for an old version of MATLAB to find out its syntax.

You shouldn't be trying to access the internal `tree` property directly. If you want to get it, use `get(tr, 'Pointers')`. It's an array listing which branches are connected to which other branches/leaves.

Comment: thanks a lot. (I was going to buy a dog and name him sam by the way.) I like matlab and I'm willing to learn it as much as I can. I am still confused about your last paragraph there. What do you mean to use get(tr, 'Pointers')? I already know that tr.tree is a matrix which has two columns and the number of rows is the same as the number of branches. I just need to figure out what exactly is each row, because I need to rewrite it.

Comment: `tree` is not a field of a struct, it's a private property of the `phytree` object. So if you type `tr.tree`, you'll get an error message saying that the property is not accessible. If you want to access it, you need to do that using the `get` method as I suggested. Even if you modify the resulting array, you will not be able to set the value of the property to your modified version - you'll need to construct a new `phytree` object from scratch with the `phytree` command.

Comment: thanks again. But during the debugging, when I type tr.tree in the command line, I do get the matrix there without error messages. By the way, what I need to modify is the cluster function in the bioinformatics too box. I just thought I need to understand the default code to modify it at my will. So, I do not need to construct a new phytree object.

Comment: Fine - yes, when you're debugging and within the workspace of the `cluster` method (note that `cluster` is not a function, it's a *method* of the `phytree` object), you can directly access the `tree` property as it's no longer private when inside the method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One  more thing, what exactly is the matrix tr.tree ? I mean, what does the i-th row of this matrix represent in terms of the phytree tree?

Comment: Type `doc phytree`. To create a `phytree` object directly rather than via `seqneighjoin`, you need to supply an input array describing the connectivity of the tree - this is the same thing as `tr.tree`. The doc page gives a description of what the rows of the array mean, with an example.

Comment: could you please take a look at this question? I truly appreciate that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856999/to-understand-the-phytree-object-in-matlab

Comment: The only difference between tr.tree and get(tr,'Pointers') is that we can not access tr.tree outside of the methods of phytree object directly, right? So, what if I need to get the dist or names properties of the phytree object?

Comment: For `dist` you can use `get(tr, 'Distances')`. The internal `names` variable is a concatenation of the leaf names, branch names and node names. You can use `get(tr, 'LeafNames')`, `get(tr, 'BranchNames')` and `get(tr, 'NodeNames')` to get them individually. Look at `get.m` in the directory `toolbox/bioinfo/bioinfo/@phytree` to find out more detail.