# to understand the phytree object in matlab

Tags: matlab

I asked the similar question here: [what exactly is the phytree object in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836048/what-exactly-is-the-phytree-object-in-matlab).
Now this is what I did to try to get it.

```
clear;
d=[4,2,5,4,5,5];
z=seqneighjoin(d);
view(z)
get(z, 'Pointers')
```

This  is the output:

ans =

```
     1     2
     3     5
     4     6
```

And the phytree figure in the following. For my understanding, this matrix is the same as the tree field of the phytree object. What is  the relation between this matrix and the figure?

[image]

Comment: Please use imgur.com to upload your image and post it here. Here is some formatting help. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should interpret the array in the following way.

Firstly, you have the four nodes 1, 2, 3 and 4. In the graph you attach, node 1 is labelled Leaf 1; node 2 is labelled Leaf 3; node 3 is labelled Leaf 2; and node 4 is labelled Leaf 4.

Then take each row of the array in turn.

The first row indicates that we first join nodes 1 and 2 - we now call this node 5, as it's the smallest number greater than the four nodes we already have. On the graph, this is the node connecting Leaf 1 and Leaf 3.

Then the second row indicates that we next join nodes 3 and 5 - we now call this node 6, as again it's the smallest number after node 5. On the graph, this is the node connecting the previous join to Leaf 2.

Then the third row indicates that we lastly join nodes 4 and 6 - we don't need to call it anything as it's the final root node, but it would be node 7. On the graph, this is the node connecting the previous join to Leaf 4.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: It makes a lot of sense now. Thanks a lot for your help, sam.

Comment: So the nodes 1, 2, 3, and 4 are usually in the same order as the drawing of the pytree? I mean, usually the nodes go from 1 to 4 as one go from top to bottom when look at the tree figure?